# Calling object position from object in array?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, cocos2d-iphone

i have a sprite in an array when calling it like this

```
[c1 objectAtIndex:0];
```

I want to call on the position of the sprite so like:

```
[c1 objectAtIndex:0].position.x;
```

Is there a way to do this or will i have to create another array that contains the sprite positions. Here is my problem:

```
if (mySpritePointers [nSprite]->position.x == myXPoints [nPoint] && mySpritePointers[nSprite]->position.y == myYPoints [nPoint]) {
```

i get an error 'struct CCSprite' has no member named 'position'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call method for value of objectAtIndex with cast.

```
((CCSprite *)[c1 objectAtIndex:0]).position.x;
```

Or

```
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[c1 objectAtIndex:0];
sprite.position.x
```